# find all employees' names who has a manager that lives in the same city as them

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to "find all employees' name who has a manager that lives in the same city as them." For this problem, we have two tables. We need to make a query.

"employee"
The employee table that we can refer to has both normal employees and managers

| employeeid | name | projectid | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jeff | 1 | new york |
| 2 | larry | 1 | new york |
| 3 | Linda | 2 | detroit |
| 4 | tom | 2 | LA |

"Managertable"
Our manager table which we can refer to with mangerid = employeeid

| projectid | mangerid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Right now I have found a way to get just the employees and filter out the managers, but now I am trying to figure out the next step to get to the comparison of managers and employees. Would this just be another subquery?

```
SELECT name  
FROM employee e
WHERE employeeid not in( 
SELECT mangerid
FROM Managertable pm
INNER JOIN employee e
ON pm.mangerid= e.employeeid);
```

Expected result :

| employee name |
| --- |
| jeff |

Comment: Why not join the employee table to the manager table and then use a `WHERE`?

Comment: You field names in the description don't match neither your field names in the tables nor the ones in your query.

Comment: I updated the field names in my query and my description.

Comment: Why Jeff is in the output? He's from new york and supervised by Linda from detroit.

Comment: you are not the wrong @lemon, I updated by swapping the projectid in the employee table.  I apologize for the several mistakes I made trying to convey the problem.

Comment: The tables are not logically designed. For example, the way it is says, Every employee or manager has 1 manager. This is not correct. Because a manager can't have herself as a manager.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easient way to achieve this would be like this:

```sql
SELECT
  e.*
FROM employee e
  inner join Managertable mt on e.projectid = mt.projectid
  inner join employee manager on mt.mangerid = manager.employeeid
WHERE
  e.city = manager.city
  and e.employeeid <> manager.employeeid;
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. There is no reason, though, to outer join the tables, because we are only looking for matches. Change your outer joins to inner joins for that reason. Then, you alreaady know the employee's manager, so you can replace `and e.employeeid NOT IN (SELECT managertable.mangerid FROM Managertable)` by a mere `and e.employeeid <> manager.employeeid`.

Comment: You are right - before employees 2 and 3 were managers to each other so I went with a subquery but with current data, it looks like it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `projectid` is relevant in your question because you didn't mention that as a requirement or restriction. Here's a method using a CTE to get the managers and their cities, then join to it to find employees who live in the same city as a manager.

```
with all_managers as (
 select distinct m.managerid, e.city
 from manager m 
 join employee e 
   on m.managerid = e.employeeid 
   )
select e.name 
from employee e 
join all_managers a 
  on e.city = a.city
 and e.employeeid <> a.managerid;
```

| name |
| --- |
| jeff |

But it you want us to assume that an employee reports to only that manager as listed in the projectid, then here's a modification to ensure that is met:

```
 with all_managers as (
  select distinct m.managerid, e.city, e.projectid
  from manager m 
  join employee e 
    on m.managerid = e.employeeid 
   )
select e.name 
from employee e 
join all_managers a 
  on e.city = a.city
 and e.projectid = a.projectid
 and e.employeeid <> a.managerid;
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7XNBgxf4jXgebXvjFsPC7p/1)

Comment: This query will match any manager's city with any employee's city. It's missing the conjoined project condition.

Comment: @lemon Exactly. The OP didn't mention that projectid is meant for anything. I called that out in my answer.

Comment: I'll update with a second version to make that a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is a correlated subquery in which we look up the employee's manager's city.

```
select e.name
from employee e
where city =
(
  select m.city
  from managertable mt
  join employee m on m.employeeid = mt.managerid
  where mt.projectid = e.projectid
  and m.employeeid <> e.employeeid
);
```

The same thing can be written with an `EXISTS` clause, if you like that better.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the table structure you're showing, something like this might work

First find the employee ids of employees who have managers in the same city, then join it back on employee to retrieve all data from the table

```
;WITH same_city AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT e.employeeid
        FROM employee AS e
  INNER JOIN managertable AS mt ON  e.projectid = mt.projectid
  INNER JOIN employee     AS m  ON mt.managerid =  e.employeeid
       WHERE e.city = m.city
)
    SELECT e.* 
      FROM employee 
INNER JOIN same_city AS sc ON e.employeeid = sc.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need two joins:

- one between "*managers*" and "*employees*" to gather managers information
- one between "*managers*" and "*employees*" to gather employees information with respect to the manager's projectid and city.

```
SELECT employees.name
FROM       managers
INNER JOIN employees managers_info
        ON managers.mangerid = managers_info.employeeid
INNER JOIN employees 
        ON managers.projectid = employees.projectid
       AND managers_info.employeeid <> employees.employeeid
       AND managers_info.city = employees.city
```